# Picture missing when export using matlab surf function

Tags: image, matlab, cdata, surf

I'm new of here![enter image description here][1]

I want to export an picture in 3d space

so I using surf function

```
img = imread('IMG_3630.JPG');
yImage = [0 0;100 100]; %# The z data for the image corners
surf([0 100],[0 100],zImage,... %# Plot the surface
'CData',img,...
'FaceColor','texturemap');
colormap(map)
```

it works on matlab but when export to file the picture is missing

I wish that the export file  look like this :
http://ppt.cc/0-uo

but the file exported look like this :
http://ppt.cc/ZJfb

I'm sorry that I'm also a new of matlab

thx for help

Comment: I have succefully done this ,but another question come up,
when I add a bar on it the picture gone again.
---
1.[picture what I want](http://ppt.cc/qBtz)  2.[picture output](http://ppt.cc/dkY7)

Comment: the first problem is solved by this :  [IND,map] = rgb2ind(img,32); surf([100 0],[0 100],zImage,... %# Plot the surface 'CData',IND,'FaceColor','texturemap'); colormap(map)

Answer (score 0):

To your new question, did you try typing in `hold on` before adding the bar?

Comment: Yes,I did.
I solve the new problem,by doing this: [IND,map] = rgb2ind(img,32);IND = im2double(IND)*255; thx

Comment: [clown](http://ppt.cc/1tkU) that's quite strange,it works on clown example,but fail in my picture